# @Method breaking routing

Tags: symfony

I've been working with Symfony2 recently, and I've been using annotations for routing, instead of the standard yml or PHP.

I've managed to get my head around most of it, but I'm having trouble using @Method to limit what type of http requests get a response from a controller.

I'm currently using:

```
/**
* @Route("/contact/", name="_contact")
* @Method({"GET", "POST"})
*/
```

and getting an error that states `Cannot import resource "C:\wamp\www\jimmy\src\Scott\BlogBundle/Controller/" from "C:/wamp/www/jimmy/app/config\routing.yml".`

If I remove the @Method line completely the page loads as normal. I've read the documentation on symfony about @Method and they do the same @Method line in their examples, so I'm really not sure where I have gone wrong.

My routing.yml in app/config is:

```
scott_blog:
    resource: "@ScottBlogBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have forgot to use the namespace Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method . If that is the case , add

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
```

Comment: Thank you! I really had no idea what was missing... I'll have to get more used to this namespace stuff I think.